# Reshuffle elements in std:::map<>

Tags: c++, stdmap

Lets say I have a `std::map` with

```
a[1] = "One";
a[2] = "Two";
a[3] = "Three";
```

and this map is represent strings that user added in the list control.

Now, the user decides to drag the item 1 at the bottom of the list control.

Is there an easy way to reshuffle the map so that it is:

```
a[1] = "Two";
a[2] = "Three";
a[3] = "One";
```

Or maybe I chose a wrong data structure to hold data?

P.S.: I can't use `std::vector`, because it's not a sorted container and I need to process string in that order.

Comment: Your "sorting" is effectively by index. Which would make `vector` effectively a "sorted container" for this purpose, since it always has the indices in order. Can you explain how this would *not* work with a `vector` that just subtracted `1` from each of the "keys" to make them zero-based? Heck, with a `list` or `deque`, you'd get `O(1)` "reshuffling" as you put it (`list` could even make it move-free/copy-free).

Comment: @ShadowRanger, not sure what you mean? Are you saying I should make the line number and a string a class and use it as a container? Something like `sruct item { long pos,; string text;; }} vector<item> items;`.  The problem with it is that vector is not a sorted container, so when loop thru the element I'm still going to see "One", "Two", "Three". That's why I said `vector will not suffice`.

Comment: And I mean `for( item: items ) // processing item`

Comment: Use a `std::deque` like so: `int i = 1; for (item : items) { /* do stuff with i and item */; ++i; }`. When you need to move an item from front to back, `deq.push_back(std::move(deq.front())); deq.pop_front();`). It's not sorted. But that doesn't matter, your "pos" *is* the sort key, and you can compute it implicitly as you iterate; merely being reorderable is all you need, you never needed sorting. The `deque` would purely store `string`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, move is not necessary front to back - it could be back to front or front to the middle. It all depends on the user - how (s)he will want to re-shuffle.

Comment: Sure, then you can use a `std::list<string>` (that lets you splice nodes around to reorder arbitrarily), or continue using `std::vector`/`std::deque` and make room to splice it into the correct place, whatever. The `std::map` is not gaining you anything here; you need the strings to be in a specific defined order, and *whatever* order they are in is the same order that you'd use to generate the associated positions. You don't need a sorted data structure, you just need an ordered one, and you can choose whatever method you like to maintain that order.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, can you put some (pseudo-)code? I am sorry - I don't see how to make it work...

Comment: @ShadowRanger, my current code using vector...

Comment: see also [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

Answer (score 2):

I know your post claim's you would be unable to use a `std::vector` to store the elements as it is "not a sorted container" however, as ShadowRanger pointed out in his comment, if your use of integer keys indicates that it would be more than possible to implement a similar structure to what you are doing with `std::map` with `std::vector`. Using the indices of the vector as your keys. That way if you wished to iterate over the vector in ascending key order, you could simply iterate over the vector in order. You could even access the elements using the `int` keys you used for your map, just starting with 0 instead of 1.

As for moving the elements, you could use some code like this

```
template <typename Iter>
void shiftBack(Iter begin, Iter end){
    for(;end > begin; --end){
        *end = std::move(*begin);
    }
}

template <typename Iter>
void shiftFront(Iter begin, Iter end){
    for(;begin < end; ++begin){
        *(begin - 1) = std::move(*begin);
    }
}

template <typename Iter>
void moveElem(Iter elemPos, Iter newPos){
    if(elemPos == newPos){
        return;
    }

    auto temp = std::move(*elemPos);

    if(elemPos > newPos){
        shiftBack(newPos, elemPos);
    } else {
        shiftFront(elemPos + 1, newPos + 1);
    }

    *newPos = std::move(temp);
}
```

This code is just an example that follows the general idea for what to do, I make no promises that it will work without error.